# Mutation Observer fails to detect original element, does detect its duplicate

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I have written a Chrome extension that loads a script with `run_at` set to `document_start`.

My script uses Mutation Observer in order to invoke some code upon the addition of an element with id `X` to a certain webpage.

That element is created when the page first loads, and then recreated when part of the page reloads following some button click.

My mutation observer fails to detect that element in either case.

However, if I duplicate the element (Developer Tools > Elements > element > context menu > Duplicate element), then my mutation observer does detect the duplicate.

I ran a test: I changed the id of some random element to `X`. It was not detected. That has made me suspect the original element is first created and then has its id assigned or updated. I am not sure how I could prove of refute this theory (the process of generating the webpage code looks very complex, with layers and layers of scripts involved, and I have very little experience).

Does this theory make sense? Can I observe an id change? If the theory does not make sense or if it is impossible to observe an id change, what alternatives do I have?

Thank you!

---

Edit:

My code looks like this:

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        for (let i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
            if (mutation.addedNodes[i].id == "X") {
                alert("X detected!");
            };
        };
    });
});

observer.observe(document, {
    attributes: true,
    characterData: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
});
```

Comment: Without a [mre] it's really hard for anyone to help you

Comment: Thank you for this comment. There's no public access to the website, and the code is very complicated. I don't think I can provide such an example. I was hoping a theoretical discussion would help me better understand the issues involved and bring me closer to a solution.

Comment: Well you might find that by building  simple version of your own in a page you control then adding/modifying/removing elements and attributes etc that you find a better set up for the observer. From a theoretical perspective MutationObservers can be configured many different ways and we have zero insight into how yours is set up

Comment: I've edited the original post, does that help in any way? I'm not sure how to build a simple version as I don't really understand what's going on there. That's why I started coming up with theories. At least my first question should not require an example, I think: is it possible to observe an id change?

Comment: Ok but this is a bit like chicken before the egg stuff. You need to play with a version you control and do dom changes in order to get a better understanding , especially with the wide variety of configuration possibilities. Building a simple version of your own may quickly unlock where the issue is

Comment: One thing to note is you aren't doing anything with attribute changes, only addednodes. I'm not sure what you are working with in the page or if you need to even run code when attributes are changed....just an idea though. Muattion Observer API is fairly complex and not for the faint of heart

Comment: But that's the thing, I don't know how to reproduce the failure to detect the element. When I load a static HTML file, a similar Mutation Observer manages to detect any element. And when I duplicate the element in the actual webpage, the Mutation Observer manages to detect it as well. I'm not sure how to continue from there. I'm not even sure how to test my theory that the id is being changed. What should I try?

Comment: Are there classes on the element? Changing existing element id is not commonly done. You could do some logging of ids in same container perhaps. This is too hard to guess at without ever seeing the actual document

Comment: Doesn't "attributes: true" mean I am doing something with attribute changes? I don't have any previous experience with Mutation Observer, if you can shed some light, please do.

Comment: Means the Observer is listening for them but you aren't running any code when any attributes do change. mutation.addedNodes is only a collection of nods added...not modified. You are only scratching at the surface of what can be done with an Observer like this

Comment: Thanks to your last comment, I've managed to make progress (thank you very much!). Now I'm able to detect changes in the id attribute (such changes do occur!). Can I extract from the mutation object information that would tell me if the mutated element is the one I'm interested in (in this case, if the new id is the right one)?

Comment: Should  have access to old and new values for the attribute

Comment: Right, MutationRecord.target gives me the element. BUT now that I can detect id's being added or changed (and that happens A LOT!), I can see that the specific id I'm interested in isn't being assigned. So I basically have no idea what's going on. Neither when I listen (or observe...) for addition of nodes with that id nor when I listen for that id being assigned to an existing node I can't detect it. And yet it's there. What am I missing?

Comment: No idea. I think i've gone as far as a I can as this is all still very abstract to me having seen none of it in my own developer tools. Sounds like you are making some progress though and that's a good thing

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate all your help!